# Can't add css to switch in html

Tags: html, css

I'm using label And class of switch but can't add css property to check box so that i can create switch even span in not working.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline - block;
  width: 60 px;
  height: 34 px;
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label>
```

Comment: Please provide more information like code sample.

Comment: Very unclear...

Comment: @Santosh added my html and css code see what's wrong

Comment: I think your looking for this https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MmxxOz

Comment: Can you add a more detailed explanation of **what do you want to achieve, what is the problem you're facing and how can we help you** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  background: #000000;
  }
```

```html
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span></label>
```

Please check above code I have tried that it's working

Comment: Am I the only one who wonders how this is the right answer, since it doesn't change anything from the original.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, but as far as I understood, you are trying to give some styles to your elements, and it seems that your style doesn't apply on your `checkbox`.

Anyways, your style is working fine, I've just added a `background` property to show you that your styles have been applied without any problems.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round">foo</span>
 </label>
```

If you are trying to give custom styles to your checkbox, read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

*Welcome to the StackOverflow community, and the more specific your question can be, you will get better, to the point answers... Good Luck!*

Answer (score 0):

css is identifying input like below

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked{
   //if checked then property
}
```